# How to count unique number of IDs which has values greater than 0?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am working on a promotional dataframe which looks something like this

| ID | Yrmo | Views | Whatsapp | Store Visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan-21 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | Feb-21 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Jan-21 | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | Feb-21 | 4 | 1 | 2 |

There are over 50 promotion columns and over a million rows in my dataframe. Now I want to see in a month, how many IDs have views>0, Whatsapp>0 and other promotion channels >0.

I was thinking of running a "for loop" in which

1. I will first groupby at a channel level to count values>0
2. Keep merging it to empty dataframe

This is the code I

```
cols = df.columns[2:].to_list()
df_month = pd.DataFrame(df['Yrmo'].unique())

df_month.columns = 'Yrmo'
for i in cols:
    temp_df = df[df[i]>0]
    df_grouped = temp_df.pivot_table(index = ['Yrmo'], values = ['ID'], aggfunc  = 'nunique')
#    
    df_grouped = df_grouped.reset_index()
    df_grouped.rename(columns = {'ID':i},inplace=True)

    df_month = df_month.merge(df_grouped, on = ['Yrmo'], how = 'left').fillna(0)
    if df_grouped.shape[0]==0:
        df_month[i] = 0
```

However, this is very time-consuming given the size of data.. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Is there more than one row for each month? More data and an example of expected output would make your requirement clearer. Also please show any code you have produced, even if 'slow'.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the output will look like but this command `pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID', 'Yrmo'], value_vars=list(df.columns[2:]), var_name='channel').groupby(['channel', 'Yrmo'])['value'].sum().reset_index(name='sum')` will unpivot and group the dataframe based on the promotional channels (columns) which you can get the summation and/or filter based on your needs. See below for sample.

```
>>> df
   ID    Yrmo  Views  Whatsapp  Store Visits
0   1  21-Jan      1         2             0
1   1  21-Feb      1         1             1
2   2  21-Jan      2         5             0
3   2  21-Feb      4         1             2
>>> grouped_by_channel = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID', 'Yrmo'], value_vars=list(df.columns[2:]), var_name='channel').groupby(['channel', 'Yrmo'])['value'].sum().reset_index(name='sum')
>>> grouped_by_channel
        channel    Yrmo    sum
0  Store Visits  21-Feb      3
1  Store Visits  21-Jan      0
2         Views  21-Feb      5
3         Views  21-Jan      3
4      Whatsapp  21-Feb      2
5      Whatsapp  21-Jan      7
```